# Import pcap on raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pcap

I'm trying to load the module pcap of the python library  pypcap 1.2.2, but when i try to import it, i got the following error:

```
import pcap
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/pcap.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/pcap.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/pypcap-1.2.2-py2.7-linux-armv6l.egg-tmp/pcap.so: undefined symbol: pcap_set_immediate_mode
```

my system info are:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.19.3+ #35 PREEMP armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you install the `libpcap-dev` package?

Comment: @pchaigno yes i've installed libpcap-dev

Comment: What version of libpcap-dev do you have?

Comment: apt-cache policy libpcap-dev
    libpcap-dev:
  Installed: 1.3.0-1
  Candidate: 1.3.0-1

Comment: That's a very old version. Linux 3.19.3 too. What's your distribution? Are there no updates? or maybe you can't update for some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pypcap requires `pcap_set_immediate_mod`. Unfortunately, that function was [**added in libpcap v1.5.0**](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/commit/48bc6c35b191857f39b628bd586bd94a03fd13d7) and you have libpcap v1.3.0-1. It looks like pypcap requires `pcap_set_immediate_mod` [since v1.2.1](https://github.com/pynetwork/pypcap/commit/409626b0f964a640b248abf959e1dca84090aeaa).

---

**Solution 1**

Install a more recent version of `libpcap-dev`. If you can't find one available in your repositories, you can try to [install it from sources](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/c0c6e23ee5f625a59c560522ec000a9b00fee67a/INSTALL.txt).

**Solution 2**

Downgrade pypcap to a version < v1.2.1. That's not guaranteed to solve your issue though, since some other function might be required once you downgraded. I couldn't find any documentation on which version of libpcap is required for each version of pypcap :-/

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, i downgraded pycap to 1.1.3 and now i can import it. I have to check all methods now!

Comment: If it imported fine, it's probably okay. If a function was missing, it would have thrown an error.